# addEventListener for click event is overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm pretty new to HTML/JS and am trying to learn all the oddities. In trying to get this to work, I learned that only one `Element.onclick = function() {}` is allowed and if you try to add more the previous ones will be overwritten. But now I'm facing the same thing by using `Element.addEventListener("click", function() {})`. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body id="body">

</body>
</html>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    for (var buttonText of ["item1", "item2", "item3"]){
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = buttonText;
      button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(`${buttonText} was clicked!`);
      });
      document.getElementById("body").append(button);
    }
  }
</script>
```

No matter which button is clicked, the console always says `item3 was clicked!`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the scope of the variable. `addEventListener` will add an event and that time though the call back will fire but the loop have finished it's execution & `buttonText` will be updated with latest value. This is causing `buttonText` to be always `item3`. One option is to replace `for (var buttonText of ["item1", "item2", "item3"]) {` with `for (let buttonText of ["item1", "item2", "item3"]) {`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (let buttonText of ["item1", "item2", "item3"]) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = buttonText;
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(`${buttonText} was clicked!`);
    });
    document.getElementById("body").append(button);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='body'></div>
```

Another option is you can create a `closure` and an `IIFE`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (var buttonText of ["item1", "item2", "item3"]) {
    // start of IIFE
    (function(txt) {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = txt;
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(`${txt} was clicked!`);
      });
      document.getElementById("body").append(button);

    }(buttonText))

  }
}
```

```html
<div id='body'></div>
```

Comment: Ah, `let` does the trick! Now to go Google the difference :)